# Delete using where not exists

Tags: sql-server, sql-delete

I am trying to delete records that exist in a master file where the account number, which consists of three fields mn_no, sb_no, and dp_no, are not in transaction tables.  Because the account number may be in one or more transaction tables, I need to test for its presence in all.  When I run the following query, MS-SQL returns an incorrect syntax error near a in line 1.

```
DELETE
FROM SYACTFIL_SQL a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT b.mn_no
            ,b.sb_no
            ,b.dp_no
        FROM gltrxhst_sql b
        WHERE a.mn_no = b.mn_no
            AND a.sb_no = b.sb_no
            AND a.dp_no = b.dp_no
        )
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT b.mn_no
            ,b.sb_no
            ,b.dp_no
        FROM gltrxfil_sql b
        WHERE a.mn_no = b.mn_no
            AND a.sb_no = b.sb_no
            AND a.dp_no = b.dp_no
        )
    AND a.mn_no <> '00000000'
```

Answer (score 8):

You have incorrect syntax here. Do the following:

```
DELETE  a
FROM    SYACTFIL_SQL a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT b.mn_no ,
                            b.sb_no ,
                            b.dp_no
                     FROM   gltrxhst_sql b
                     WHERE  a.mn_no = b.mn_no
                            AND a.sb_no = b.sb_no
                            AND a.dp_no = b.dp_no )
        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT b.mn_no ,
                                b.sb_no ,
                                b.dp_no
                         FROM   gltrxfil_sql b
                         WHERE  a.mn_no = b.mn_no
                                AND a.sb_no = b.sb_no
                                AND a.dp_no = b.dp_no )
        AND a.mn_no <> '00000000'
```

Or

```
DELETE  FROM SYACTFIL_SQL
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT b.mn_no ,
                            b.sb_no ,
                            b.dp_no
                     FROM   gltrxhst_sql b
                     WHERE  SYACTFIL_SQL.mn_no = b.mn_no
                            AND SYACTFIL_SQL.sb_no = b.sb_no
                            AND SYACTFIL_SQL.dp_no = b.dp_no )
        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT b.mn_no ,
                                b.sb_no ,
                                b.dp_no
                         FROM   gltrxfil_sql b
                         WHERE  SYACTFIL_SQL.mn_no = b.mn_no
                                AND SYACTFIL_SQL.sb_no = b.sb_no
                                AND SYACTFIL_SQL.dp_no = b.dp_no )
        AND mn_no <> '00000000'
```